“Only vs itself” which one should I use?
Should I use "itself" or "only" when I say I don't have something.
Example:
a. itself: I don't have insta ID itself
b. only: I don't have insta ID only

Why use either?

As @Michael Harvey says, there is no need to use either. Just say: "I don't have an Instagram ID".

"I don't have X itself" (but I have something very like it). "I don't have X only" (but I also have Y and Z).

Great explanation @Drupalguy  thanks...

I have noticed itself being used in this way in Indian English. In any other English, as far as I know, it is ungrammatical.
If I correctly understand what you intend, you don't need an extra word there, as the comments say; but if you need to emphasise the thing you haven't got, I would say something like "I don't have an Insta ID exactly", meaning "I don't have the exact thing that is an Insta ID".

Thanks @ColinFine you clarified it...
